# Android Custom View with custom attributes declared programmatically

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a library (JAR) that contains a custom button. I'd like to have custom attributes associated with the button such as buttonStyle (Round, Square, Oval etc) as an example. Since I'd like to package the button in a JAR and not as an android project I'm prevented from using XML layouts and other resource files.

I am having trouble finding a way to declare custom attributes to the button via java. There's plenty of documentation on how to add custom attributes via a resource XML but then this would not enable me to package my library as a JAR.

Is there a way to declare custom attributes to a custom button programmatically or does it need to be declare via a attribute XML?

Thanks

Comment: Attributes are defined in the R file, which is generated by parsing xml files. Since they're all `int`s in the end, you could maybe just declare your own constants, but the user wouldn't be able to reference them via xml in their layouts.
tl;dr No way to do this cleanly.